# How do I incorporate a slide out/burger menu to an existing tab bar controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, swift4

So I want to create a slide out menu. I want the menu to slide out when a tab bar item/button is touched.
So far, I have created a tab view controller with 4 different tab bar buttons. Each button leads to a different view controller and each view controller has been separated into their own storyboard.

I made an attempt of adding a UIViewController for the side menu to the class that is already established as a UITabBarController and I got the error:

Multiple inheritance from classes 'UITabBarController' and 'UIViewController'.

Is there a way around this?

I appreciate all the help

Comment: Please show your code in question. PS: UITabBarController inherited from UIViewController already.

Comment: I created the tab bars by using storyboards instead of code, which probably wasn't a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps tend to have a top level container like a `Tab Bar Controller` that cannot be embedded inside a View. The approach here is to wrap the main body and the left menu each inside a `Container View`. Now both of these elements can be arranged inside a wrapper `View Controller`.

[image: Container Storyboard]

A `Scroll View` is used to simulate opening and closing the menu by shifting the left menu on/off-screen.

### Containing View Controller

Drop a `View Controller` onto the Storyboard. This is your entry point into the app.
Check the box for `Is Initial View Controller`.
Change the `Simulated Size` from `Fixed` to `Freeform`. Set the Width to 568 so we can fit the menu and Tab Bar side-by-side.
Create a new Swift file and set this View Controller's class to ContainerVC.

```
import UIKit
class ContainerVC : UIViewController {
}
```

### Scroll View

Inside Container View Controller, drop in a `Scroll View` and add constraints in all directions.

Check the box for `Scrolling Enabled`. This allows you to pan the screen to slide the menu. You might need to disable this if your app uses horizontally scrolling elements.

Check the box for `Paging Enabled`. This snaps the menu to either the open or closed state.

Uncheck the box for `Bounces`. You don't really want to scroll past the right edge of the Tab Bar Controller.

Wire the IBOutlet to ContainerVC:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

### Left Container

The left container holds the menu, and is not quite the full width of the screen.

Drag a `Container View` into the left side of the `Scroll View`.

Add constraints for top, left, and right to the containing `Scroll View`.

Hard-code the width to 260.

Add a constraint for `Equal height` with the ContainerVC's embedded View. Note: don't constrain the height to the Scroll View.
Delete the embedded `View Controller` that came with the `Container View`.

Drop a new `Table View Controller`(Any view according to your need) onto the Storyboard, and connect using an embed segue.

### Right Container

The right container holds the main body of your app, namely the `Tab Bar Controller`.

Drag a second `Container View` into the right side of the `Scroll View`.

Add constraints to the containing `Scroll View` for top, right, and bottom. Connect horizontally to the left Container View you created earlier.

Constraint both `Equal height` and `Equal width` to the ContainerVC's embedded View.

**Note:** do not constrain these to the Scroll View.

[image: setConstraintsFromContainers]

Again, delete the embedded View Controller that came free with the `Container View`. Instead, create an `embed` segue to the `Tab Bar Controller`.

To create a little visual separation between the two containers, add a `Runtime Attribute` to the Right Container. Add `layer.shadowOpacity` with a number of `0.8`.

### Tabs

Embed each tab inside a `Navigation Controller`. Doing so gives you a free `Navigation Bar`.

Drag a `Bar Button Item` into the top left corner of each `Navigation Bar`.

Wire an `IBAction` to each controller. These will fire off a `Notification` to the great-grandfather `ContainerVC` to toggle the menu.

```
@IBAction func toggleMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
  NotificationCenter.default().post(name: Notification.Name("toggleMenu"), object: nil)
}
```

Finally add the below code into ContainerVC:

```
class ContainerVC : UIViewController {

    // This value matches the left menu's width in the Storyboard
    let leftMenuWidth:CGFloat = 260

    // Need a handle to the scrollView to open and close the menu
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        // Initially close menu programmatically.  This needs to be done on the main thread initially in order to work.
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.closeMenu(animated: false)
        }

        // Tab bar controller's child pages have a top-left button toggles the menu
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ContainerVC.toggleMenu), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "toggleMenu"), object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ContainerVC.closeMenuViaNotification), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "closeMenuViaNotification"), object: nil)

        // Close the menu when the device rotates
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ContainerVC.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)

        // LeftMenu sends openModalWindow
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ContainerVC.openModalWindow), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "openModalWindow"), object: nil)

    }

    // Cleanup notifications added in viewDidLoad
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func openModalWindow() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "openModalWindow", sender: nil)
    }

    @objc func toggleMenu() {
        scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0  ? closeMenu() : openMenu()
    }

    // This wrapper function is necessary because closeMenu params do not match up with Notification
    @objc func closeMenuViaNotification(){
        closeMenu()
    }

    // Use scrollview content offset-x to slide the menu.
    func closeMenu(animated:Bool = true){
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: leftMenuWidth, y: 0), animated: animated)
    }

    // Open is the natural state of the menu because of how the storyboard is setup.
    func openMenu(){
        print("opening menu")
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
    }

    @objc func rotated(){
        if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.current.orientation) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                print("closing menu on rotate")
                self.closeMenu()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ContainerVC : UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("scrollView.contentOffset.x:: \(scrollView.contentOffset.x)")
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = false
    }
}
```

The code accomplishes the following:

- Listen for the "toggleMenu" notification
- Implement the toggleMenu method by opening or closing based on the
  current contentOffset.x
- Open and close the menu by changing the contentOffset-x.

Hopefully you have a simple slideout left menu on which to build the rest of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use UITabBarController, and manage tab controls using one view controller and buttons actions.

Comment: So I should get rid of my UITabBarController and create the tab bars programmatically using a view controller?

Answer (score 0):

@Ajo answer is correct . embed hamburger and tabbar inside a container view .

Complete source code u can find from the link below

[source code link](https://github.com/prathamsalvi27/MyProjects)

There is also a detailed tutorial I found
[tutorial link](https://medium.com/@prathamsalvi27/hamburger-menu-on-uitabbarcontroller-swift-d2ac929937a3)

use initial view controller as container view .
use notifications for slide in / out

[image: storyboard image]